# Dataloss at connection android tablet -> lan - RS232 converter, but not on android tablet ->winpc pc -> converter

Tags: android, windows, networking, serial-port, data-loss

i have a big problem and i doubt about my intellect... I connected my android tablet (intenso tab814) to a RS232 converter (USR-TCP232-E) via a router (TL-WR740-N) and i send 7 hexadezimal bytes in a block, kinda 03 20 05... with further numbers. My problem is, if i let my tablet send, the converter receives the data, but does not submit it to a listening program on an pc behind the converter complete. There are often complete blocks missing (bnot single Bytes, but the whole command line i send), but if i send my data via tablet to another PC, and let HIM do the sending work to the converter every single byte arrives. It may be a bit dazzling, but i dont know, where this problem could belong to. My App sends every block correctly (the pc is able to receive)

The converters yellow RJ45 port-LED blinks, but i does not give the data to the listening pc.

For better understand:

Tablet(selfpogrammed app) sends data -> router -> converter (everytime blinks) seldom gives the command -> PC(selfwritten listening programm(not written by me, but by the one, i am the follower of, not familiar with language.)

But if i:

Tablet(same app) -> router -> PC (receives all the data) -> router -> converter always give the data to the listening progamm ->pc

What is the matter here? Why does the converter gives the data from app -> pc to listening pc, but not from app to listenign pc?

Tablet is connected via W-Lan to router, the pc's via RJ45-cable, the converter either. Using TCP/IP converter as server.

PLS HELP Q_Q

*EDIT:*
configuration:

Baud Rate:  115200bits/second
Data Size:  8 bits/characterParity:  None NoneOddEvenMarkSpace
Stop Bits:  1bit(s) 
Flow Control:  None 
Local Telnet Port Number:  2001
Remote Telnet Port Number:  N/A
Telnet Mode:  TCP Server 
Telnet Server IP:  N/A . . .
Telnet Timeout:  0seconds  seconds (< 256, 0 for no timeout)

UART packet Time:  10ms  ms (< 256)

UART packet length:  200

EDIT:

forgot sth to mention. the converter is via RS232 to an USB converter from RS232 to USB connected. Its receiving lamp does not blink, when the listening programm does not show my commands, but if the programm spits my lines out, the USB-part blinks too. So the converter receives, but does not give it to the USB. But only if i use my tablet. Same interval all the time.

Comment: How is the UART/RS232 configured? Is handshake enabled? -- How is the intermediate PC software in scenario 2 implemented which runs on the PC? Could it contribute to solve any timing/data loss issues on the UART?

Comment: edited my question, the same thing works once, if i connect to a pc, but not if i cconnect to a converter? think not data or timing issue. Maybe wrong, added the configuration

Comment: I cannot recommend 115k2bps on a UART without flow control. I must say I maybe don't understand your setup completely due to your language (why don't you describe it in a more simple way?), but I would start with the UART. -- What do you mean by "only if I use my tablet"? You use your tablet in both scenarios. If there is another scenario, you need to describe it.

Comment: i meant with "only if i use..." when theres no pc between tablet and converter... and the 115k was just for trying.. our standert is 9,6k that was is described directly under 'For better understand:'

Comment: Once more. PCs have problems receiving 115k2bps via UART without flow control. What is the relevance of the 9k6 if you set this up for 115k2?

Comment: i just did it a few mins ago, just to have a look if it would change anything it runs on 9,6k again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my own fault, forgot to use a bufferedoutputstream, now it works.